# Select variables in one data frame to plot from another

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, plot

I have large data sets where I am doing exploratory screenings for correlations. I want to do a correlation test to identify significantly related variables, and then plot these variables against each other.

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = c(1.5*(1:9), 10), c = 2*(1:10), d = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T))
cor_data <- corr.test(data)

sig_cor <- ifelse(cor_data$p <0.05, cor_data$r, NA)

sig_cor_long <- sig_cor %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(var1 = rownames(sig_cor)) %>% 
  gather(var2, value = r, -var1) %>% 
  drop_na(r) %>% 
  filter(r != 1)
```

This identifies pairs a-b and b-c as significantly correlated, so I want to plot those. How can I automate this process of selecting the paired variables from sig_cor_long to plot via ggplot from data? An example plot that I want to create for each correlated pair would be:

```
ggplot(data, aes(a, b)) +
geom_smooth(method = 'lm')+
geom_point(shape = 21, color = 'darkblue', fill = 'white')
```

I want to have a function to input into ggplot to tell it to plot all the var1 and var2 pairs identified in sig_cor_long for which the raw data are in data.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with automate?

Comment: I want to automate the selection of variables to plot from data. So, I will automatically have a graph of a vs. b and b vs. c (and in the case of the real large data set, hundreds more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, this is one way of plotting e.g. all the plots where there is significant correlation (in a list, so you could do anything with them)

```
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange,
  ifelse(cor_data$p <0.05, cor_data$r, NA) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    gather(pair, val, -rowname) %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    filter(val != 1) %$%
    map2(rowname, pair, ~ggplot() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(data[, .x], data[, .y])) + geom_point(aes(data[, .x], data[, .y])))
)
```